# New attiny85 fuse bits are all set by default

Tags: microcontroller, avr, arduino-uno, winavr

I've been working on an Attiny85 project and am trying to program the microcontroller using WinAVR and Burn-O-Mat to burn the code onto the chip.
After i plug the chip to the arduino ISP and try to read the fuse bits using Burn-O-Mat, I see all the bits HIGH for all three of my Attiny85 chips and am unable to write over them with the default fuse bits, the application says error writing fuses.

I have bought one of the attinys from the market and got this problem with that one at first, so I thought I had bricked it somehow or it was bricked to being with. So then I ordered two more from amazon and when  I tried to read their fuse bits, again, all the bits were marked/HIGH.

How can I rewrite fuse bits?

Are these chips bricked?

Am I using the Burn-O-Mat wrong?

What else could be the issue?

Comment: Never used Burn-O-Mat, but it sounds like it isn't even reading the fuse bytes. Especially because you can't even write them. What about performing an "erase"? Does the controller work at all?

Comment: what do you mean with "all bits high"? fuse bits are meant to be set, if their value is zero. however - Burn-O-Mat shows a checkmark in the box, if if is set (bit is zero)